# Required field requires migration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I removed the data annotation `Required` from a field. Do I need to use migrations to apply that in the DB? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a migration you go to the Package Manager Console

- Run command -> Enable-Migrations
- Run command -> add-migration [migration_name]
- Run command -> update-database

To apply on production database you can create a script in the following manner

```
Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration:[NameOfMigrationYourDatabaseIsRunning]
```

Comment: I did that in local test. Now I must make the same in the server. I need just update the server files as always and it will apply the migration in the server?

Comment: what is "NameOfMigrationYourDatabaseIsRunning"? I dont got it. Is it the name of migration i just created using `add-migration [mig_name]`? After run that command, I just need to upload the project files as always? Sorry im too noob here, and Im afraind mess the server.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
update-database -verbose
```

in the package manager console